# Sorted indexes of a random numbers

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, bubble-sort

In which way i can find **indexes** of my **random** numbers and store them.

**Example:**

> 300, 2, 43, 12, 0, 1, 90

```
Values  ->  0  1  2  12  43  90  300
Indexes ->  0  1  2  3   4   5   6
```

So. Can i store instead of my values their indexes?

Like This

```
300  2  43  12  0  1  90
 6   2  4   3   0  1  5
```

And will it possible for negative numbers also?

Comment: Store the random numbers in an array, and sort the array?

Comment: Use a `struct` to hold the value and the original index, before sorting.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No I just want to store indexes of numbers. If i have a numbers of array [5 3 2 1] i want to change these values with their indexes. [3 2 1 0]

Comment: But since you get the indexes from the sorted collection of (random) numbers, the indexes can't be calculated beforehand. You *must* store the numbers and then sort them to get the indexes. This array that you sort could be temporary, you could throw it away once you have the indexes, and store the value-index pair some other way for later use.

Comment: Perhaps, instead of drawing from a uniform probability density, maybe a [uniform cumulative distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution)? That would save on steps, (`O(n)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: (correction to my previously posted incorrect solution)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int val;
    int in0;
    int in1;
} pair_t;

int cmpVal( const void *a, const void *b ) { return ((pair_t*)a)->val - ((pair_t*)b)->val; }
int cmpOrg( const void *a, const void *b ) { return ((pair_t*)a)->in0 - ((pair_t*)b)->in0; }

int main() {
    int i;
    int unsort[] = { 300, 2, 43, 12, 0, 1, 90 };
    const int n = sizeof unsort/sizeof unsort[0];

    // Make a copy in unsorted order including orginal sequence.
    pair_t *worken = malloc( n * sizeof *worken );
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        worken[i].val = unsort[i], worken[i].in0 = i;

    // Sort by value ascending
    qsort( worken, n, sizeof pair_t, cmpVal );

    // Register this sequence with each element
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        worken[i].in1 = i;

    // Restore original sequence
    qsort( worken, n, sizeof pair_t, cmpOrg );

    // Copy the indices (of sorted version) to 'persistant' array.
    int sorted[n] = { 0 };
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        sorted[i] = worken[i].in1;

    // Toss 'working' buffer.
    free( worken );

    // List original sequence
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        printf( "%4d", unsort[ i ] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    // List corresponding indices (as if sorted)
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        printf( "%4d", sorted[ i ] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 300   2  43  12   0   1  90
   6   2   4   3   0   1   5
```

Trivial assignment loop to `"replace values with indices"` in original array left out for clarity...

EDIT #2:

The OP suggests the unsorted array is to have its values replaced(!) with indices indicating the sort order.

This following does as much with the proviso that array values are not near the top end of values for `int`s.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void show( int u[], size_t cnt ) { // Show current array values
    for( size_t i = 0; i < cnt; i++ )
        printf( "%4d", u[ i ] );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

void oddSort( int u[], size_t cnt ) {
    show( u, cnt );
    // Succesively find and replace highest values with decreasing large int values.
    int peak = INT_MAX;
    for( size_t set = 0; set < cnt; set++ ) {
        int maxID = 0;
        while( u[maxID] >= peak ) maxID++; // find first non-replaced value
        for( size_t i = maxID + 1; i < cnt; i++ )
            if( u[i] < peak && u[i] > u[maxID] )
                maxID = i;
        u[maxID] = peak--;
    }

    // transpose down to 0, 1, 2...
    for( size_t i = 0; i < cnt; i++ )
        u[i] -= peak + 1;
    show( u, cnt );
}

int main() {
    {
        int u[] = { 300, 2, 43, 12, 0, 1, 90 };
        oddSort( u, sizeof u/sizeof u[0] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    {
        // Test with negatives (coincidentally lowest value in first pos)
        int u[] = { -256, 300, 2, 43, 12, 0, 1, 90 };
        oddSort( u, sizeof u/sizeof u[0] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 300   2  43  12   0   1  90
   6   2   4   3   0   1   5

-256 300   2  43  12   0   1  90
   0   7   3   5   4   1   2   6
```

Comment: Please, don't cast the value returned from `malloc()`.  Just `#include <stdlib.h>` to use malloc, and let it return a `void *` that the compiler will convert to the appropiate pointer type.  Not in C.

Comment: your old compiler probably requires to `#include <malloc.h>` instead of `<stdlib.h>`.  Anyway, if your old compiler is pre-ansi enough to use a `char *malloc()` definition, then you still had better to provide a proper prototype, than allow it to convert a integer (the default return type of an undeclared function) into a pointer (which is only valid aceptable in architectures that have `int` and pointers of the same size)  I recommend that to you do, because doing the cast hides many errors arising from this misuse (just silents the warning), but you are on your way now.  Good luck.

Comment: the cast doesn't repair the problem, just silents the compiler.

Comment: By the way, I have not blamed you for the solution being correct or not... but for the misuse of the cast to `malloc()`.  If you don't accept it or you want better credit for the solution you gave voluntarily, I would be making a bad job if I didn't signal that problem, that casually works only in architectures in which pointers and integers have the same image size (e.g. 32bit, not 64bit, or the mixed models of ancient Microsoft compilers _compact_ and _large_ 16bit memory models)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247750/discussion-between-luis-colorado-and-fe2o3).

Comment: May I edit it, so you can blame me for doing it bad?

Comment: @LuisColorado No worries, and my apologies... Was tired and grumpy at the end of the day, and have received many 'snipes' that miss the point(s) of suggested algorithm(s). Thank you for making the change, and, again, sorry for my (deleted) responses that were impolite. All good `:-)`

Comment: You are welcome, now it's me who goes to bed.... :)